# Old Browsers TLS 1.0 and 1.1

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, iis, pci-compliance

We've removed older versions of TLS and ciphers from our site that is an HTTPS e-commerce hosted on a Windows 2008 R2 Server.

We've had people using older browsers/operating systems saying that they now can't access the site but as we're PCI complaint I'm reluctant to reverse the changes.

I can't think of a way to catch these people and at least redirect them to a http site to show a nicer message to the customers

Is anyone able to suggest a way this can be achieved or is it a case of the older browsers won't even communicate with the the old browsers over https to redirect them with the old protocols disabled

Answer (score 1):

With IIS there is no way to do this. And you should'nt: https://community.qualys.com/thread/12758

Comment: Please summarize the important parts of the web URL you included in case the link goes dead.